# Unity M2MQTT WEBGL. SocketException: Could not resolve host

Tags: unity-game-engine, mqtt, unity-webgl

I am trying to build a WebGL application that uses m2mqtt to retrieve data on Unity. The application works fine in editor and windows build but this error comes out when I am trying to run it as WebGL.

[image].

Here's the error that pops out.

I've tried removing firewalls and CORS from my web browsers and its not working. Was wondering if WebGL from Unity does not support these kinds of connections.

Comment: Hi user20785749, for legibility, please post your error as code instead of an image; thanks!

Comment: That error is a name resolution problem (DNS) check the machine the browser is running on can ping/nslookup that host name

Comment: Id expect a different error but for some reason its not able to look the name up to get the ip address